# Где учить DirectX 12 C++

Tags: c++, directx

Посоветуйте материал для изучения DirectX 12 под C++. Желательно чтобы материал был на русском языке

Comment: начните изучать английский. После изучения кол-во документации по нужной вам теме вырастет в разы

Comment: https://www.rastertek.com/tutindex.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем вопросе слишком много вариаций. C++ под DirectX есть двух версий: C++/CX (устаревший, но много документации) и WinRT/C++ (новая версия, минус не так много примеров кода и документации). Это для версии 12, а для 11 ещё есть C#.

Важно отметить также, что DirectX версий 11 и 12 -- это абсолютно разные API. Не просто новые, а именно концептуально разные. Версия 12 также поддерживает новые технологии: трассировку лучей (raytracing), шейдеры сетки (mesh shaders).

И ещё один, главный момент, DirectX, а скорее, мы имеем ввиду её графическую часть, Direct3D -- это API на COM-объектах. Т.е. существуют его проекции и на другие языки (C#, C++/CX, C++/WinRT, Rust/WinRT).

В результате, на данном этапе развития DirectX, обучение будет такое: если выбрана версия 12, то документацию с примерами смотреть для Direct3D12 C++/CX, а конкретную семантику функций, уже на выбранной COM-проекции.

[Руководство по программированию Direct3D 12 (на русском)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/direct3d12/directx-12-programming-guide)

Comment: Ни C++/CX, ни WinRT/C++ DirectX не затрагивают, так как API DirectX не является частью Windows Runtime API. C# тем более ни при чем.

Comment: DirectX, точнее, Direct3D являются частью Windows Runtime API. И C++/CX и WinRT/C++ являются языками для Direct3D11 и 12. C# является языком программирования для Direct3D 11. Интересно, что вы Rust не упомянули! Как раз, в нём видно явно пространство имён `windows::Win32::Graphics::Direct3D12` (https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Graphics/Direct3D12/index.html) А пример, C++/CX вот: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-d3d12createdevice

Comment: По ссылкам DirectX находится в группе традиционных API win32, а не Windows Runtime API. Где по ссылке microsoft вам привиделся C++/CX - неизвестно. В принципе, DirectX  можно использовать из любого языка, поддерживающего вызовы С функций. Однако на практике мало смысла использовать что-то, кроме обычного C++.

Comment: Похоже у вас всё в голове запутано... Если говорить о современной, актуальной версии Windows Runtime API (WinRT, начиная с версии 1803 (10.0.17134.0)), то в ней конкретно находится Direct3D API. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cppcx/visual-c-language-reference-c-cx?view=msvc-170 "С помощью C++/CX можно создать: Игры Windows на базе DirectX и приложения, активно использующие графику." На практике, имеет смысл использовать тот язык, который больше нравится (если для него есть WinRT). Вот мне больше нравится Rust/WinRT, который даёт доступ ко всем Windows Runtime API, включая Direct3D.

Comment: Все, вопрос я более конкретизировал.

Comment: То, что с помощью C++/CX можно было использовать DirectX не означает, что DirectX был частью Windows Runtime API. Как я уже писал выше, DirectX всегда был и остается частью традиционных API win32.